# Can I sync folders in two devices over Bluetooth?

Tags: sync, bluetooth, file-management, wifi-direct

Can I sync folders and files in two Android devices? These devices are physically nearby, but not connected to the same Wi-Fi network. They are connected to the internet using their respective mobile data connection.

Maybe there's a possibility using e.g. Bluetooth and maybe use Wi-Fi Direct when large data transfer is needed?

I dont want  AirDrop or NearbyShare like functionality. It is rather like Resillo or Syncthing over bluetooth.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). I've rephrased your question slightly so it becomes on-topic; hope it still meets your intentions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't really say "sync" but the closest tool you can use is : [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp&hl=en).

Its free (with ads) with option of non ad version at a price, but still good enough for the former option.

> It allows you to use your smartphone to browse, explore and manage
> files of any Bluetooth ready device, using File Transfer Profile (FTP)
> and Object Push Profile (OPP): you can also receive files and send
> contacts!

It provides its own OBEX layer, additionally you can cut, copy, move, paste, delete multiple items using the integrated explorer of this application.

[image]